# How to convert the following set of queries' output to a view in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below code in SQL Server and I want the same output but as a view. How do I write a view to give this output? I want the result from the first query basically along with the count of distinct people id for each occupancy id but I can't use group by in that query.

Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    pp.PeopleID,  
    od.OccupancyID,
    pp.Gender
INTO 
    t1
FROM
    dimPeople AS pp  
LEFT JOIN 
    OccupanciesPeople AS op ON op.PeopleID = pp.PeopleID 
                            AND op.CompanyID = pp.CompanyID  
LEFT JOIN 
    OccupancyDetail AS od ON op.OccupancyID = od.OccupancyID 
                          AND op.CompanyID = od.CompanyID
WHERE 
    od.OccupancyEndDate IS NULL 
    AND op.DateLeftOccupancy IS NULL 
    AND pp.DateOfDeath IS NULL 

SELECT
    OccupancyID, COUNT(DISTINCT peopleID) AS PeopleCount  
INTO
    t2 
FROM
    t1 
GROUP BY 
    OccupancyID

SELECT
    t1.*,
    t2.PeopleCount, t2.[HouseHold Person] 
FROM
    t1 
JOIN
    t2 ON t1.occupancyID = t2.OccupancyID 

DROP TABLE t1
DROP TABLE t2
```

Comment: You can't have three queries in one view. But it looks like you could get what you want by using window functions or `rollup/grouping sets`. What are you actually trying to do, and why do you need those temporary tables? By the way, your first query should probably not have a `distinct` or `left join`, instead it should use `where not exists`. But without knowing what it's supposed to do, can't say

Comment: I need those temporary tables since I need count of distinct op.peopleid as people count for that particular occupancy ID. However, when I am trying in a single query it is throwing syntax error.

Comment: Of course it is possible in one query, but please be much clearer about what result you are trying to get. Preferably sample input data and expected output, and a description of the exact logic

Comment: A view is not what you need. Edit your question to present sample data and what you are trying to achieve and someone can refactor it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If those queries work the way you want (spoiler: they don't - you don't define `t2.[HouseHold Person]` when you create t2), you could replace the 2 "into" tables with Common Table Expressions and get your results.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.MyView AS
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT DISTINCT
    pp.PeopleID,  
    od.OccupancyID,
    pp.Gender
FROM
    dimPeople AS pp  
LEFT JOIN 
    OccupanciesPeople AS op ON op.PeopleID = pp.PeopleID 
                            AND op.CompanyID = pp.CompanyID  
LEFT JOIN 
    OccupancyDetail AS od ON op.OccupancyID = od.OccupancyID 
                          AND op.CompanyID = od.CompanyID
WHERE 
    od.OccupancyEndDate IS NULL 
    AND op.DateLeftOccupancy IS NULL 
    AND pp.DateOfDeath IS NULL 
), t2 as (
SELECT
    OccupancyID, COUNT(DISTINCT peopleID) AS PeopleCount  
FROM
    t1 
GROUP BY 
    OccupancyID
)
SELECT
    t1.PeopleID,
    t1.OccupancyID,
    t1.Gender,
    t2.PeopleCount
FROM
    t1 
JOIN
    t2 ON t1.occupancyID = t2.OccupancyID;
```